# Unusual stack overflow when inserting nodes in binary tree

Tags: common-lisp, binary-tree, stack-overflow, clisp

CLISP Version: 2.49

Leaf Node

```
(value (NIL) (NIL))
```

Non-Leaf Node

```
(value (value (NIL) (NIL)) (NIL))
```

Code ("format" for debug only)

```
; (nil) means NULL
(defun binary-insert (root obj <) 
(if (null (cdr root))
    (progn 
        (format t "In Null [~A] => " root) 
        (setf (car root) obj) 
        (format t "mid [~A] => " root) 
        (setf (cdr root) '((nil) (nil))) 
        (format t "[~A]~%" root))
    (if (funcall < obj (car root))
        (progn 
            (format t "In Left [~A] => " root) 
            (binary-insert (nth 1 root) obj <) 
            (format t "[~A]~%" root)) ; Left
        (progn 
            (format t "In Right [~A] => " root) 
            (binary-insert (nth 2 root) obj <) 
            (format t "[~A]~%" root)) ; Right
        )
    )
)
```

Test

```
[1]> (load "binary_tree.lisp")
;; Loading file binary_tree.lisp ...
;; Loaded file binary_tree.lisp
T
[2]> (setf *glb-rt* '(NIL))
(NIL)
[3]> (binary-insert *glb-rt* 10 #'<)
In Null [(NIL)] => mid [(10)] => [(10 (NIL) (NIL))]
NIL
[4]> *glb-rt*
(10 (NIL) (NIL))
[5]> (binary-insert *glb-rt* 5 #'<)
In Left [(10 (NIL) (NIL))] => In Null [(NIL)] => mid [(5)] => [
*** - Lisp stack overflow. RESET
```

It seems the program died after executing

```
(setf (cdr root) '((NIL) (NIL)))
```

Thanks....

[Update]

Before (setf (cdr root) '((NIL) (NIL))), the "root" is (5)

Another test

```
[6]> (setf glb-ls '(5))
(5)
[7]> (setf (cdr glb-ls) '((NIL) (NIL)))
((NIL) (NIL))
[8]> glb-ls
(5 (NIL) (NIL))
```

Comment: Please [format](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Indentation) your code properly. As it is presented now, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered in the CLISP FAQ [How do I avoid stack overflow?](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-stack)

In your case the very first suggestion works: after

```
(setq *print-circle* t)
```

we get

```
In Left [(10 (NIL) (NIL))] => In Null [(NIL)] => mid [(5)] => [#1=(5 #1#  (NIL))]
```

i.e., you are mistakenly creating a circular structure.

PS. You now owe me [10 zorkmids](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine) :-)

Comment: Oh!!! Thanks a lot!!! .........But it is not over i think >..<

Why I got a circular list instead of (10 (5 (NIL) (NIL)) (NIL))???
Before (setf  (cdr root) '((NIL) (NIL))), the "root" is (5)
    <blink>
    I make a test below
    [6]> (setf glb-ls '(5))
    (5)
    [7]> (setf (cdr glb-ls) '((NIL) (NIL)))
    ((NIL) (NIL))
    [8]> glb-ls
    (5 (NIL) (NIL))
    </blink>
PS: Zorkmid..coin O..o ?? I have CNY coins only  ╮(╯▽╰)╭

Comment: you now need to [close this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439) (which has been answered!) and ask a new question about your bug, but first you need to learn how to indent your code.